# close() is not closing socket properly

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server

I have a multi-threaded server (thread pool) that is handling a large number of requests (up to 500/sec for one node), using 20 threads.  There's a listener thread that accepts incoming connections and queues them for the handler threads to process.  Once the response is ready, the threads then write out to the client and close the socket.  All seemed to be fine until recently, a test client program started hanging randomly after reading the response.  After a lot of digging, it seems that the close() from the server is not actually disconnecting the socket.  I've added some debugging prints to the code with the file descriptor number and I get this type of output.

```
Processing request for 21
Writing to 21
Closing 21
```

The return value of close() is 0, or there would be another debug statement printed. After this output with a client that hangs, lsof is showing an established connection.

SERVER  8160      root   21u     IPv4           32754237                            TCP localhost:9980->localhost:47530 (ESTABLISHED)

CLIENT   17747      root   12u     IPv4           32754228                            TCP localhost:47530->localhost:9980 (ESTABLISHED)

It's as if the server never sends the shutdown sequence to the client, and this state hangs until the client is killed, leaving the server side in a close wait state

SERVER  8160      root   21u     IPv4           32754237                  TCP localhost:9980->localhost:47530 (CLOSE_WAIT)

Also if the client has a timeout specified, it will timeout instead of hanging.  I can also manually run

```
call close(21)
```

in the server from gdb, and the client will then disconnect.  This happens maybe once in 50,000 requests, but might not happen for extended periods.

Linux version: 2.6.21.7-2.fc8xen
Centos version: 5.4 (Final)

socket actions are as follows

SERVER:

```
int client_socket;
struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client_addr);  

while(true) {
  client_socket = accept(incoming_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_len);
  if (client_socket == -1)
    continue;
  /*  insert into queue here for threads to process  */
}
```

Then the thread picks up the socket and builds the response.

```
/*  get client_socket from queue  */

/*  processing request here  */

/*  now set to blocking for write; was previously set to non-blocking for reading  */
int flags = fcntl(client_socket, F_GETFL);
if (flags < 0)
  abort();
if (fcntl(client_socket, F_SETFL, flags|O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
  abort();

server_write(client_socket, response_buf, response_length);
server_close(client_socket);
```

server_write and server_close.

```
void server_write( int fd, char const *buf, ssize_t len ) {
    printf("Writing to %d\n", fd);
    while(len > 0) {
      ssize_t n = write(fd, buf, len);
      if(n <= 0)
        return;// I don't really care what error happened, we'll just drop the connection
      len -= n;
      buf += n;
    }
  }

void server_close( int fd ) {
    for(uint32_t i=0; i<10; i++) {
      int n = close(fd);
      if(!n) {//closed successfully                                                                                                                                   
        return;
      }
      usleep(100);
    }
    printf("Close failed for %d\n", fd);
  }
```

CLIENT:

Client side is using libcurl v 7.27.0

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
CURLcode res;
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback );
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, write_tag );

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Nothing fancy, just a basic curl connection.  Client hangs in tranfer.c (in libcurl) because the socket is not perceived as being closed.  It's waiting for more data from the server.

Things I've tried so far:

Shutdown before close

```
shutdown(fd, SHUT_WR);                                                                                                                                            
char buf[64];                                                                                                                                                     
while(read(fd, buf, 64) > 0);                                                                                                                                         
/*  then close  */
```

Setting SO_LINGER to close forcibly in 1 second

```
struct linger l;
l.l_onoff = 1;
l.l_linger = 1;
if (setsockopt(client_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &l, sizeof(l)) == -1)
  abort();
```

These have made no difference.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT -- This ended up being a thread-safety issue inside a queue library causing the socket to be handled inappropriately by multiple threads.

Comment: Are you 100% positive no other thread could possibly be using the socket when you call `close` on it? How do you do your non-blocking reads?

Comment: I'm afraid I just logged in here and remembered this issue.  I found out later that there was a thread safety issue in a queue used to pass the connections around.  There was no bug here.  Sorry for the misinformation.

Answer (score 80):

Here is some code I've used on many Unix-like systems (e.g SunOS 4, SGI IRIX, HPUX 10.20, CentOS 5, Cygwin) to close a socket:

```
int getSO_ERROR(int fd) {
   int err = 1;
   socklen_t len = sizeof err;
   if (-1 == getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char *)&err, &len))
      FatalError("getSO_ERROR");
   if (err)
      errno = err;              // set errno to the socket SO_ERROR
   return err;
}

void closeSocket(int fd) {      // *not* the Windows closesocket()
   if (fd >= 0) {
      getSO_ERROR(fd); // first clear any errors, which can cause close to fail
      if (shutdown(fd, SHUT_RDWR) < 0) // secondly, terminate the 'reliable' delivery
         if (errno != ENOTCONN && errno != EINVAL) // SGI causes EINVAL
            Perror("shutdown");
      if (close(fd) < 0) // finally call close()
         Perror("close");
   }
}
```

But the above does not guarantee that any buffered writes are sent.

Graceful close: It took me about 10 years to figure out how to close a socket. But for another 10 years I just lazily called `usleep(20000)` for a slight delay to 'ensure' that the write buffer was flushed before the close. This obviously is not very clever, because:

- The delay was too long most of the time.
- The delay was too short some of the time--maybe!
- A signal such SIGCHLD could occur to end `usleep()` (but I usually called `usleep()` twice to handle this case--a hack).
- There was no indication whether this works. But this is perhaps not important if a) hard resets are perfectly ok, and/or b) you have control over both sides of the link.

But doing a proper flush is surprisingly hard. Using `SO_LINGER` is apparently *not* the way to go; see for example:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- https://www.google.ca/#q=the-ultimate-so_linger-page

And `SIOCOUTQ` appears to be Linux-specific.

Note `shutdown(fd, SHUT_WR)` *doesn't* stop writing, contrary to its name, and maybe contrary to `man 2 shutdown`.

This code `flushSocketBeforeClose()` waits until a read of zero bytes, or until the timer expires.  The function `haveInput()` is a simple wrapper for select(2), and is set to block for up to 1/100th of a second.

```
bool haveInput(int fd, double timeout) {
   int status;
   fd_set fds;
   struct timeval tv;
   FD_ZERO(&fds);
   FD_SET(fd, &fds);
   tv.tv_sec  = (long)timeout; // cast needed for C++
   tv.tv_usec = (long)((timeout - tv.tv_sec) * 1000000); // 'suseconds_t'

   while (1) {
      if (!(status = select(fd + 1, &fds, 0, 0, &tv)))
         return FALSE;
      else if (status > 0 && FD_ISSET(fd, &fds))
         return TRUE;
      else if (status > 0)
         FatalError("I am confused");
      else if (errno != EINTR)
         FatalError("select"); // tbd EBADF: man page "an error has occurred"
   }
}

bool flushSocketBeforeClose(int fd, double timeout) {
   const double start = getWallTimeEpoch();
   char discard[99];
   ASSERT(SHUT_WR == 1);
   if (shutdown(fd, 1) != -1)
      while (getWallTimeEpoch() < start + timeout)
         while (haveInput(fd, 0.01)) // can block for 0.01 secs
            if (!read(fd, discard, sizeof discard))
               return TRUE; // success!
   return FALSE;
}
```

Example of use:

```
   if (!flushSocketBeforeClose(fd, 2.0)) // can block for 2s
       printf("Warning: Cannot gracefully close socket\n");
   closeSocket(fd);
```

In the above, my `getWallTimeEpoch()` is similar to `time(),` and `Perror()` is a wrapper for `perror().`

**Edit:** Some comments:

- My first admission is a bit embarrassing. The OP and Nemo challenged the need to clear the internal `so_error` before close, but I cannot now find any reference for this. The system in question was HPUX 10.20.  After a failed `connect()`, just calling `close()` did not release the file descriptor, because the system wished to deliver an outstanding error to me. But I, like most people, never bothered to check the return value of `close.`  So I eventually ran out of file descriptors `(ulimit -n),` which finally got my attention.
- (very minor point) One commentator objected to the hard-coded numerical arguments to `shutdown()`, rather than e.g. SHUT_WR for 1. The simplest answer is that Windows uses different #defines/enums e.g. `SD_SEND`. And many other writers (e.g. Beej) use constants, as do many legacy systems.
- Also, I always, always, set FD_CLOEXEC on all my sockets, since in my applications I never want them passed to a child and, more importantly, I don't want a hung child to impact me.

Sample code to set CLOEXEC:

```
   static void setFD_CLOEXEC(int fd) {
      int status = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD, 0);
      if (status >= 0)
         status = fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, status | FD_CLOEXEC);
      if (status < 0)
         Perror("Error getting/setting socket FD_CLOEXEC flags");
   }
```

Comment: I wish I could vote this up twice. This is only the second sample of a correctly closed socket I have seen in the wild.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey - Do you have a reference for "errors ... will cause close() to be ignored"?  Preferably from the POSIX spec?

Comment: Testing this out now... I'll post once it's finished

Comment: I think `shutdown` should be operated with the corresponding macros `SHUT_RD` etc

Comment: I'm afraid this is still happening with this shutdown sequence.  @JosephQuinsey--could you list some documentation for close() being ignored for any reason?

Comment: Read up on the glorious [`FINWAIT`](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-2.htm) feature of TCP.

Comment: Your code fixed an issue in my client, where it could not reconnect immediately after being disconnected by the server, because the client sent a SYN before even ack'ing FIN.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. I was just `close()`ing a socket but it was still blocking on `accept()`. Once I used `shutdown()`, it's no more blocking. You saved many hours to me. If this really works out platform independent overall, I will be happy to award a +50 bounty to you!

Comment: ' The above does not guarantee that any buffered writes are sent': it most certainly does, to the extent that anything does. This is built into TCP. The shutdown before close is entirely redundant unless the socket FD has been shared with another process.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is trying to figure out how `getSO_ERROR()` contributes at solving the problem: it turns out that calling `getsockopt` with `SO_ERROR` will first fetch the error status, and then reset it. This information was not easy to find for me, nor I am sure it's portable. The following man page documents this behavior: https://linux.die.net/man/3/getsockopt But the same man page (`man 3 getsockopt`) on my distro does not (RHEL8).

Answer (score 2):

Great answer from Joseph Quinsey. I have comments on the `haveInput` function. Wondering how likely it is that select returns an fd you did not include in your set. This would be a major OS bug IMHO. That's the kind of thing I would check if I wrote unit tests for the `select` function, not in an ordinary app.

```
if (!(status = select(fd + 1, &fds, 0, 0, &tv)))
   return FALSE;
else if (status > 0 && FD_ISSET(fd, &fds))
   return TRUE;
else if (status > 0)
   FatalError("I am confused"); // <--- fd unknown to function
```

My other comment pertains to the handling of EINTR. In theory, you could get stuck in an infinite loop if `select` kept returning EINTR, as this error lets the loop start over. Given the very short timeout (0.01), it appears highly unlikely to happen. However, I think the appropriate way of dealing with this would be to return errors to the caller (`flushSocketBeforeClose`). The caller can keep calling `haveInput` has long as its timeout hasn't expired, and declare failure for other errors.

ADDITION #1

`flushSocketBeforeClose` will not exit quickly in case of `read` returning an error. It will keep looping until the timeout expires. You can't rely on the `select` inside `haveInput` to anticipate all errors. `read` has errors of its own (ex: `EIO`).

```
     while (haveInput(fd, 0.01)) 
        if (!read(fd, discard, sizeof discard)) <-- -1 does not end loop
           return TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like a bug in your Linux distribution.

The [GNU C library documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Closing-a-Socket.html) says:

> When you have finished using a socket, you can simply close its file
>   descriptor with `close`

Nothing about clearing any error flags or waiting for the data to be flushed or any such thing.

Your code is fine; your O/S has a bug.

Comment: Leaning towards this answer.  It will take some work to get another os up to test.  I'll revisit this once I've tested.  I want to add in this link from @Nemo as it seems relevant to the question. and the response it was attached to has been deleted.  https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/checkforeintrwheninvokingclosethinkagain

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, as changing my thread-safe queue to use semaphores rather than pthread conditions has inexplicably (to myself anyway) solved the issue.

Comment: `Nothing about clearing any error flags or waiting for the data to be flushed or any such thing.` Arguably, "waiting for the data to be flushed" falls under "when you have finished using a socket".

Comment: @DavidMFrey That would mean there's a near 100% chance your code had/has a logic error/bug or race condition instead of it being an OS bug.

Comment: This supposition is vanishingly unlikely. If `close()` didn't work, nothing would work.

Comment: @EJP You missed the entire point of my answer. To close a socket, all you have to do is call `close()`. This is according to every standard (e.g. POSIX) and implementation (e.g. glibc) documentation anybody has cited here. If you have to do anything else to close a socket, that is a bug in your C library or O/S... And as you can see from some of the other answers here, such bugs **did** exist in various Unix implementations over the years.

Comment: @Nemo That is entirely incorrect. As just one example of how it's incorrect, imagine if there are two descriptors that reference the same socket. Calling `close` on either descriptor will *not* close the socket.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: OK, sure, if you `dup` the descriptor you would have to `close` both (obviously). Have any other examples?

Comment: @Nemo Yes, but they are even more bizarre and obscure. The point is that there's no guarantee. It really is that simple. (For example, closing the last socket descriptor of a listening socket will not always close the listening socket. The OS often uses a timer to come back and close the socket later. Linger on close is similar. The socket IS NOT CLOSED just because the descriptors are. There can be internal references as well.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My point is that `close` is a freeing operation, and closing the last descriptor associated with a resource is **all** that is needed to release that resource. The actual release could be delayed by (e.g.) the vagaries of the TCP state machine, but it must happen eventually. If some magic handshake in the application beyond `close` is needed to avoid a resource leak in the kernel, that is a bug in the O/S, period.

Answer (score 0):

include:
#include <unistd.h>

this should help solve the close(); problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).