# Why does my recv hang for large messages when the sender closes the socket?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

When I send a data from a socket and then immediately close it (without changing the default settings), small data sizes are sent successfully but large ones (> 2MB) are not.

Here is how I set up the receiver (blocking on the recv() at the end):

```
In [1]: import zmq

In [2]: ctx = zmq.Context()

In [3]: socket = ctx.socket(zmq.PULL)

In [4]: socket.connect("ipc://@foo")

In [5]: msg = socket.recv()
```

And then the sender:

```
In [1]: import zmq

In [2]: ctx = zmq.Context()

In [3]: socket = ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)

In [4]: socket.bind("ipc://@foo")

In [5]: arr = bytearray([1]*100)

In [6]: len(arr)
Out[6]: 100

In [7]: socket.send(arr); socket.close()
```

The receiver gets the data just fine:

```
In [5]: msg = socket.recv()

In [6]: len(msg)
Out[6]: 100
```

If however I use a larger message, say `arr = bytearray([1]*int(2e6))`, then the receiver keeps blocking, waiting for data.

Changing the LINGER settings don't seem to make any difference (and I believe default to infinite wait anyway).

Adding a sleep(1) between sending and closing on the sender like
`socket.send(arr); time.sleep(1); socket.close()` solves the problem: the receiver gets the data correctly.

Why is this not working without the sleep if LINGER defaults to -1?  What is the correct way to send and then immediately close a socket when dealing with larger amounts of data?

Comment: See example `flushSocketBeforeClose()` in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12730776/318716

Comment: @JosephQuinsey Very interesting, thank you.  It seems I can use zmq.Poller (analagous to your select) to loop with a small timeout till the result is an empty list.  Going to try a few combinations right now.

Comment: The main problem (as you've likely gathered) is that Zeromq does all network calls asynchronously. Your likely closing the socket before the whole message is sent.

Answer (score 0):

It hangs because it didn't receive any message (you closed the pusher too soon). If you open a new `PUSH` socket and send a short message, you'll see the `PULL` receiver is working well and still listening for new messages.

In the [ZeroMQ FAQs](http://zeromq.org/area:faq), you can read:

> **How can I flush all messages that are in the ZeroMQ socket queue?**
>
> There is no explicit command for flushing a specific message or all
>   messages from the message queue. You may set ZMQ_LINGER to 0 and close
>   the socket to discard any unsent messages.

So, basically, if you want to make sure the message was sent, then you'll need to implement a synchronization method between the nodes (i.e.: using `REQ-REP`).