# How to avoid bad FD_SET buffer overflow crash?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, macros, posix

Recently I have been bitten by the `FD_SET` buffer overflow twice. The first time is we have too much socket (1024+) to added into the `FD_SET`. This is an test case, we have disabled it, and add `assert` to detect this case.

Today we hit another related issue when we run an test case for 1000+ times. Each time, the test case will somehow trigger to allocate an socket, and later release it before the test case finished. This test case will hit `FD_SET` buffer overflow when we run 1000+ time.

We have find the root cause:

1. For each pass, the allocate socket id will increase(+1), it will not reuse the socket id in a long time. The `Operating system` is `MAC`, and I think it is an reasonable design to avoid using already released socket without error happen.
2. `FD_SET` only set the `fd_set` bit array using socket id as index, if the socket id is large, it will overflow. I think `fd_set` is an bad design.

We think the 1000+ is an reasonable number. And we don't think define MACRO to set 'fd_set' huge is not reasonable and wasting memory and CPU when wait.

We doesn't know how to resolve it, so any suggestion?

-------------Edit1----------------

It turn out there is socket leak in other place, which violate destructor should release all resource. And this make the socket id increase. 
So item #1 is not true. Operating system will reuse the socket id.
But anyway, the discuss is helpful, and the `FD_SET` is bad design, and we should using `poll()`.

Comment: If it is not reusing a file descriptor (what you called a “socket id”), you are not closing the file descriptor.  Try running `lsof` on your test program when it's been running for a while.  You will probably find many open sockets in the output.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey, the FD_SETSIZE is 1024.

Comment: JosephQuinsey and Rob mayoff If any of you can make your comments as an answer, I will mask it the accept one.

Comment: @robmayoff, I have try to run lsof on my application, seams the socket are not closed but I'm sure i have called the close from the log. Call the close function is super simple, so any comments why it doesn't close correct? And by the way, `lsof -g PID` doesn't works on debugged process, any reason?

Comment: "*... and I think it is an reasonable design to avoid using already released socket without error happen.*" I'd say this assumption is wrong. Do not use `close()`ed file-/socket-descriptors!

Comment: @alk, let me clarify it, I means if system doesn't reuse the socket-descriptor, then it will be more easy to debug and detect `using closed socket-descriptors`, because the API will never return success in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increasing limit of FD\_SETSIZE and select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976388/increasing-limit-of-fd-setsize-and-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer summarizes the solution found by the OP, and comments by rob mayoff and Joseph Quinsey.

If a program is not reusing a file descriptor (what you called a 'socket id'), it is not closing the file descriptor. Try running `lsof` on your test program when it's been running for a while. You will probably find many open sockets in the output. (But the OP says `lsof -g PID` doesn't seem to work on debugged process).

Alternatively, try `netstat -a -p --inet | grep process-name-or-pid`.

On some systems, sometimes a simple `close(fd)` for a socket is not sufficient. If your socket file descriptors are constantly increasing, then the answer [close() is not closing socket properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730477/close-is-not-closing-socket-properly/12730776#12730776) might help.

To avoid the problem with FD_SETSIZE, several writers, for example [Increasing limit of FD_SETSIZE and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976388/increasing-limit-of-fd-setsize-and-select/7977082#7977082), suggest using `poll` rather than `select`.

Finally, the OP solved the issue:

> It turned out there was socket leak in another place, which violate destructor should release all resource. And this made the socket id increase. Fixed, the operating system will reuse the socket id.
>
> But anyway, the discussion is helpful, and the `FD_SET` is bad design, and we should using `poll()`.

Note that Unix-like systems *always* (or usually) use the smallest available file descriptor. For example, the man page for `open(2)` states;

> The file descriptor returned by a successful call will be the *lowest-numbered* file descriptor not currently open for the process.

Comment: ***Edit***: The answer [Are there any platforms where using structure copy on an fd\_set (for select() or pselect()) causes problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2436796) has some info on `FD_SETSIZE` on various platforms.