# Closing socket in client crashes nodejs server

Tags: c, node.js, sockets

On C client I do:

```
socket()
connect() on port 6969
send()
//I have seen that I didn't call recv so nodejs try me to send data but My program was gone
and finally closesocket()
```

On nodejs server I receive the message so the connection is established:

```
const port = 6969;
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(connection) {
    console.log('client connected');
    connection.on('close', function() {
        console.log('conn closed');
    });
    connection.on('end', function() {
        console.log('conn ended');// that is not called
    });
    connection.on("error", function(err) {
        console.log("Caught flash policy server socket error: ");
        console.log(err.stack);
    });
    connection.on('data', function(data) {
        data = data.toString();
        console.log('client sended the folowing string:' + data);
        connection.write("Response");
        console.log('Sended response to client');
    });
});
server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('server is listening');
});
```

This is the result of my terminal:

```
server is listening
client connected
client sended the folowing string:err404
Sended response to client
Caught flash policy server socket error:
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:568:26)
conn closed
```

So I have read [Node js ECONNRESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset) already but I don't understand if this is normal why my nodejs server crash?

Edit: I found this snippet:

```
connection.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("Caught flash policy server socket error: ");
    console.log(err.stack);
});
```

This code on client side will produce the same error:

```
#ifdef WIN32
Sleep(5000);
int iResult = shutdown(sock, SD_BOTH);
printf("shutdown is called\n");
Sleep(5000);
#elif defined (linux)
sleep(5);
int iResult = shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
printf("shutdown is called\n");
sleep(5);
#endif // WIN32
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {closesocket(sock);printf("SOCKET_ERROR");}
    printf("iResult=%d",iResult);
```

Edit:
Now I catch either close event and end event: but the same error is still throwed.

Edit: I've Updated my code.
And I found where is the problem:NodeJs is trying to send me data but I've already called `shutdown()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There 2 things to consider, one in your server and one in your client code.

**Server code:**

You have to use the `end` event instead of the `close` event, see
https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_end:

```
connection.on('end', function (){
   console.log('client disconnected');
});
```

end event:

> Emitted when the other end of the socket sends a FIN packet, thus ending the readable side of the socket.

close event:

> Emitted once the socket is fully closed. The argument had_error is a boolean which says if the socket was closed due to a transmission error.

So that means, that the `close` event will occur after the `end` event.

---

**Client code:**

You have to call `shutdown` before closing the socket to prevent further reads or writes which then would cause an error because the socket is already down.

The Windows version of `shutdown` is described [here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740481(v=vs.85).aspx) and the Linux variant [here in a manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/shutdown).

Windows:

```
int ret = shutdown(sockfd, SD_BOTH); /* Shutdown both send and receive operations. */
```

Linux:

```
int ret = shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RDWR); /* Disables further send and receive operations. */
```

---

**Importance of flushing sent data:**

The `shutdown` function does not guarantees that data that is already in the buffer does not get send. It is needed that all data get's flushed before the call to `close` occur. In [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730776/8051589) is written down a nice way to do that rather than just sleep 20 ms or so.
In order to test if that is your problem you can use `Sleep(2000)` in Windows and `sleep(2)` in Linux to sleep 2 seconds between `shutdown` and `close`.

---

On [this page](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#closedown) is a nice comparison between `close/closesocket` and `shutdown`:

> You're ready to close the connection on your socket descriptor. This is easy. You can just use the regular Unix file descriptor close() function:
>
> ```
> close(sockfd);
> ```
>
> This will prevent any more reads and writes to the socket. Anyone attempting to read or write the socket on the remote end will receive an error.
>
> Just in case you want a little more control over how the socket closes, you can use the shutdown() function. It allows you to cut off communication in a certain direction, or both ways (just like close() does.) Synopsis:
>
> ```
> int shutdown(int sockfd, int how);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> shutdown() returns 0 on success, and -1 on error (with errno set accordingly.)

Comment: i use portable socket `#if defined (linux)#define closesocket(s) close(s)#endif` so on linux i have to call `shutdown(socket,SHUT_RDWR);`

Comment: @elie: Insert a sleep of 2 seconds between shutdown and close and tell me if it is working. You have to ensure that all data is flushed before closing. Shutdown just prevents new data coming.

Comment: @elie: Also you mean `if (iResult != SOCKET_ERROR) closesocket(sock);` and not `if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) closesocket(sock);` aren't you?

Comment: I have `#define SOCKET_ERROR -1ˋ. I call shutdown() and if the function fail( the function return -1 like man say) so i use as fallback closesocket(). From your answer I understand I have to call closesocket only if shutdown success.

Comment: Ok, I have tested just right now: I put sleep between send between shutdown and between closesocket=> I saw that shutdown cause the same error as closesocket. I have `printf("%d",iResult);` and that produce 0... So shutdown success but for NodeJs something went wrong. I haven't changed == to != because this error is produce before.

Comment: Now I think I know whats going wrong. You have to use `connection.on('end', function (){ ...` instead of `connection.on('close', function (){ ...`, [see here](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_end). The end event get's the FIN packet.

Comment: I call recv before shutdown the socket: No error is throw.  Is a better solution exists?

Comment: @Et7f3XIV: It was not neccessary to `use` the end event?

Comment: Yes it is redundant but i will cleanun some thing when i'm sure that the other side is really logout.