# close() does not close tcp connection if interface lost its ip address

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

My program has an established tcp connection when linux box loses its DHCP IP address lease. After that it tries to close the connection so when dhcp server recovers it will re-establish tcp connection again. It uses **SO_REUSEADDR**.
I did read this http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html but in this application reuse address is a requirement.
The way I reproduce this problem is by issuing **ifconfig etho 0.0.0.0**

However, the result of **close(sockfd)** is unpredictable. Sometimes it closes socket properly. Sometimes **netstat -ant** continuously shows
**tcp        0      0 192.168.1.119:54322     192.168.1.41:54321      (STATE)**
where **(STATE)** can one of **ESTABLISHED**, or **FIN_WAIT1**, or **CLOSE_WAIT**.

Originally my code had just close(). After reading multiple sources online, I tried some suggestions.

First I tried this (based on http://deepix.github.io/2016/10/21/tcprst.html)

```
   if (sockFd != -1) {
        linger lin;
        lin.l_onoff = 1;
        lin.l_linger = 0;
        if (setsockopt(sockFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (const char *)&lin, sizeof(linger)) == -1) {
            std::cout << "Error setting socket opt SO_LINGER while trying to close " << std::endl;
        }
        close(sockFd);
    }
```

It did not help, so I tried this (based on [close() is not closing socket properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730477/close-is-not-closing-socket-properly) )

```
bool haveInput(int fd, double timeout) {
   int status;
   fd_set fds;
   struct timeval tv;
   FD_ZERO(&fds);
   FD_SET(fd, &fds);
   tv.tv_sec  = (long)timeout; // cast needed for C++
   tv.tv_usec = (long)((timeout - tv.tv_sec) * 1000000); // 'suseconds_t'

   while (1) {
      if (!(status = select(fd + 1, &fds, 0, 0, &tv)))
         return FALSE;
      else if (status > 0 && FD_ISSET(fd, &fds))
         return TRUE;
      else if (status > 0)
          break;
      else if (errno != EINTR)
          break;
   }
}

void myClose(int sockFd)
{
   if (sockFd != -1) {
int err = 1;
   socklen_t len = sizeof err;
   getsockopt(sockFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char *)&err, &len);
        shutdown(sockFd, SHUT_WR);
        usleep(20000);
        char discard[99];
         while (haveInput(sockFd, 0.01)) 
            if (!read(sockFd, discard, sizeof discard))
    break;
        shutdown(sockFd, SHUT_RD);
        usleep(20000);
        close(sockFd);
        sockFd = -1;
    }  
}
```

As before, sometimes it closes connection, and sometimes it does not.
I understand that in this case the other side can send neither **FIN** nor **ACK**, so graceful close is just not possible.

Is there a reliable way to completely close tcp connection in such conditions?

Thank you

Comment: SO_LINGER/`close()` should certainly have helped, as it resets the connection, so you can't possibly have seen ESTABLISHED, FIN_WAIT_1, CLOSE_WAIT, etc. `shutdown()` adds no value to `close()` here; nor does reading until end of stream: if there was any data there a simple `close()` would already have reset the connection, which again you don't want to do. The problem is that if the interface has lost its IP address, it can't send or receive FIN or ACK, so the connection cannot be properly closed, so FIN_WAIT_1 is inevitable, but it should time out eventually. CLOSE_WAIT is an application bug.

Comment: NB Sleeps are just literally a waste of time in networking code, and you don't need `select()` to implement a read timeout: `SO_RCVTIMEO` already does that far more simply.

Comment: @user207421: I agree with everything what you said. However, I verified that with SO_LINGER/close connection disappears most of the time, but still sometimes it stays in ESTABLISHED mode for a very long time (I did not have enough patience to see for how long).

Comment: So `close()` must have returned an error. I hope your real code has real error-checking.